# Как объединить числа из массива в диапазоны?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с числами, нужно вывести его значения в строку, объединив при этом ближайшие числа в диапазоны:
Например: [2,3,5,10,15,16] на выходе должно получиться: `2-5, 10, 15-16`

Решение есть, но кажется избыточным, хочется либо оптимизировать это,

```js
  const numbers = document.querySelector('.numbers');
  const arr = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 15, 16]
  const arrayToRange = (arr) => {
      const result = [];
      let start = '';
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i + 1] - arr[i] !== 1) {
              if (start === '') {
                  result.push(arr[i]);
              } else {
                  const str = `${start}-${arr[i]}`;
                  start = '';
                  result.push(str);
              }
          } else {
              if (start === '') {
                  start = arr[i];
              }
          }
      }


      return result;
  };
  

 const result = arrayToRange(arr);
 
 numbers.innerText = result;
```

```html
<p class="numbers"></p>
```

либо найти более простое.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно использовать метод [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) сравнивания предыдущее и следующее значение с текущим:

```js
const src = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 15, 16]

const res = src.reduce((acc, cur, idx, arr) => (cur - 1) === arr[idx - 1] ? (cur + 1) === arr[idx + 1] ? acc : `${acc}-${cur}` : `${acc}, ${cur}`)

console.log(res)
```